# Place and retrieve multidimensional array in Session

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, session, multidimensional-array

As the title says, I need to store my Array in a Session and later on retrieve it.

Here is my Array:

```
  Dim arrStatus(,) As Object =
 New Object(,) {
        {DHID, btnEditDepHead, ddlHeads, lblDH, DepHeadStatus, DepHeadDateChanged}, _
        {MMID, btnEditMM, ddlMM, lblMM, MMStatus, MMDateChanged}, _
        {AA1ID, btnEditAA1, ddlAA1, lblAA1, AA1Status, AddApp1DateChanged}, _
        {AA2ID, btnEditAA2, ddlAA2, lblAA2, AA2Status, AddApp2DateChanged}, _
        {AA3ID, btnEditAA3, ddlAA3, lblAA3, AA3Status, AddApp3DateChanged}, _
        {EXECID, btnEditExec, ddlExec, lblEXEC, ExecStatus, ExecDateChanged}, _
        {EVPID, btnEditEVP, ddlEVP, lblEVP, EVPStatus, EVPDateChanged}, _
        {DMID, btnEditDM, ddlDM, lblDM, DMStatus, DMDateChanged}
               }

Session("arrStatus") = arrStatus
```

Code in retrieval

```
 Dim arrStatus As Object
    arrStatus = Session("arrStatus")

    For i As Integer = 0 To arrStatus.GetUpperBound(0)
        arrStatus(i, 3).visible = True
        arrStatus(i, 4).visible = True
        arrStatus(i, 5).visible = True
    Next
```

But when i run this code, my objects does not do what it should do. It does not visible = true

I need this code for multiple buttons and I need to place it inside session to avoid code repetition. Ive done a research already but I only saw simple arrays.

Comment: Just store the variable `arrStatus` to a session variable... I don't see a problem or issue here. Also I don't see any attempt on what you have tried. Please update before it's closed and or it gets voted down.

Comment: Yes I think it is easy to place it inside a Session, but my problem is on how to retrieve it. Ok copy thanks

Comment: As with any session variable, it's still the same object it was when you put it in so simply cast it when you get it out.

Comment: can you look again at my updated question @jmcilhinney

Comment: You appear to be adding controls to this array.  Do those controls that you put in even exist when you get the array out?  probably not.

Comment: it is existing because all of it exisits in my aspx page. By the way, is my Declaration of the session object in my Code retrieval correct?

Comment: You are creating an array of type `Object` and then expect VB to understand these are buttons on the way out... Like @jmcilhinney said, do these buttons even exist when you are reading out the array? I think you are misunderstanding a basic principle of web applications. You are most likely needing these buttons in a session variable because you want to do something with them AFTER a page reload, but your session variable (that array of buttons) doesn't actually refer to your ASPX page, it's a set of "orphaned" controls without a page...

Comment: So my current situation is not applicable for session? I have to re-declare them again for every Button clicks? @Jeroen . Sorry I am not yet fully familiar with web apps.

Comment: @Dale, you can store the properties of the buttons in the array if you need to keep them.But yeah, you can just create a bunch of buttons on one page and magically expect them to be there on the next.

Comment: I meant to say *CAN'T* just create a bunch of buttons... :-)